# Событие при появлении подвала в зоне видимости экрана

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно, чтобы при появлении футера в зоне видимости экрана отработало событие, при этом высота хедера и контентной части могут быть разные.

```js
var headerHeight = document.querySelector("header").clientHeight;
var contentHeight = document.querySelector(".content").clientHeight;
var footerHeight = document.querySelector("footer").clientHeight;
```

```css
header {
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.content {
  background: tomato;
  height: 2000px;
}

footer {
  height: 400px;
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>

<div class="content">
  content
</div>

<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

Comment: высота скролла + высота окна >= позиция по Y футера

Comment: в коде можно пример?

Comment: @ИльяШишлачев вы хотите автоматически прокрутить страницу до футера после загрузки документа?

Comment: нет, прокрутка не автоматическая

Comment: @ИльяШишлачев по клику или как? можно пояснить когда вы хотите прокрутить страницу до футера?

Comment: скролл страницы в обычном режимы, как к примеру эта страница, доскролили до футера появилось сообщение alert("footer")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Решение c `jQuery`

```js
var $element = $('footer');
let counter = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

  //Если скролл до конца елемента
  //var offset = $element.offset().top + $element.height();

  //Если скролл до начала елемента
  var offset = $element.offset().top

  if (scroll > offset && counter == 0) {
    alert('footer!');
    counter = 1;
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.content {
  background: tomato;
  height: 2000px;
}

footer {
  height: 400px;
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  header
</header>

<div class="content">
  content
</div>

<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

### Решение на чистом `JS`

```js
let counter = 0;

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var elementTarget = document.querySelector("footer");
  //Если начало футера
  //if(...  > (elementTarget.offsetTop - elementTarget.offsetHeight)
  //Если конец футера
  //if(... > (elementTarget.offsetTop))
  (elementTarget.offsetTop - elementTarget.offsetHeight)
  if (!counter && window.scrollY > (elementTarget.offsetTop - elementTarget.offsetHeight)) {
    alert("footer!");
    counter = 1;
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.content {
  background: tomato;
  height: 2000px;
}

footer {
  height: 400px;
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>

<div class="content">
  content
</div>

<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

Comment: js не работает, за jquery спасибо

Comment: @ИльяШишлачев почему js не работает? здесь работает, может быть что-то пропустили?

Comment: Подтверждаю, способ на чистом JS работает крайне странно. Необходимо footer делать высотой очень серьёзной, как в примере - 400px. Если меньше, то вообще не реагирует (не работает). Что в мобильном браузере, что в обычном. Это можно как то исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с использованием [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

```js
const target = document.querySelector('footer');

function handleIntersection(entries) {
  entries.map((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      alert('Footer')
    }
  });
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection);
observer.observe(target);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.content {
  background: tomato;
  height: 2000px;
}

footer {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>

<div class="content">
  content
</div>

<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дополню ответ выше, как это возможно реализовать в JS, мб поможет

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var elementTarget = document.querySelector("footer");
  if (window.scrollY > (document.querySelector("body").offsetHeight - elementTarget.offsetTop)) {
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = "/pict/icon/page_footer.ico";
  }
});
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]